# Qt Creator could not find the executable, please specify one

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I'm trying to run the `texteditor.pro` file in the `QtSDK\Examples\4.7\tutorials\gettingStarted\gsQml` directory with Qt Creator. When I try to build the project I get a window that says

> Could Not find the executable, please specify one

with three fields to load files. [Snapshot of the dialog box](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/849/46621546.jpg/).

I'm running windows 7 64bit, with Qt Creator 2.4.1

Comment: It's better to embed the screenshot in the question itself than link to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem it was a **missing dll file**, but the executable didn't ask for it, so I put all the dlls from **Qtcreator -> bin** in the same folder with the *.exe file, then I deleted file after another until I figured out what files are required.
 * It is a brute force way, but It did the job.
 * Here is the file that were missing (**libEGL.dll**)

Comment: What is '*.exe'?

Answer (score 0):

This project is not created in the normal 'Qt-executable' kind format. Rather its a 'plugin' kind project. So you cant run it directly like other projects.

*[If you will open the project files you wont find a main() function!, which is supposed to be the entrance point usually for a C++ Application. All you have are a couple C++ classes. Take that as a hint]*

About this example they have given the complete details [here](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/gettingstartedqml.html). And I quote:

> We need to compile the file dialog C++ plugin before the text editor
>   can run. To compile, enter the gsQml directory, then run qmake and
>   compile using make or nmake, depending on your platform. To run,
>   launch qmlviewer and open the texteditor.qml file.

Else:

1. You create your own project.
2. Add these class files and the respective qml files to this project.
3. Add a main and create the respective objects required.
4. Make an application viewer and give "texteditor.qml" path as its source.

Answer (score 0):

I had the `could not find executable` window pop up in my face in Ubuntu 12.10.

Here's how I got the "error":

- Created a folder named Project;
- Inside it, I ran "qmake -project" and then "qmake";
- Created a main.cpp file inside the folder;
- Opened the Project.pro file with Qt Creator and added the line "SOURCES += main.cpp" to it;
- Pressed Ctrl + R to build and run the project.

Later on I deleted the folder and created it again, but this time creating a main.cpp file before trying to run any commands. I opened the .pro file with Qt Creator, created a main function in the main.cpp file, and pressed Ctrl + R, and it built and ran!